# How to use async/await to achieve asynchronous page in asp.net webform?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, webforms, async-await

We can now use the async/await key words in ASP.NET MVC 4.

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> TestAsync()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    return Content(await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.google.com"));
}
```

But how to use it in ASP.NET WebForms?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One easy way is to just make your event handlers `async`. First, add the `Async="true"` parameter to the `@Page` directive, and then you should be able to write async event handlers as such:

```
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var client = new WebClient();
  var content = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.google.com");
  Response.Write(content);
}
```

I say "should be able to" because I haven't actually tried this out myself. But it should work.

**Update:** This does *not* work for `Page_Load` (see [this MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/b2e8c51e-2808-46d0-92e9-b825321d0af8)), but should work for other events such as button clicks.

**Update:** This *does* work for `Page_Load` in ASP.NET 4.5. Also, they added checks if you improperly use an `async` event handler. [See this video for details.](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Async-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: If the await keyword wasn't notifying the Page class about the asynchronous operation in Page_Load why would that be any different for button clicks? But thanks for the update that this is now supported.

Comment: It's actually due to the problems around `async void`. Systems that are designed with `async` in mind (e.g., WebAPI and some parts of MVC) use `Task`s exclusively. `async void` only notifies the `SynchronizationContext`, which in this case is part of the ASP.NET runtime (below WebPages/MVC/WebAPI).

Comment: Button clicks *might* work. As far as the `Page` class is concerned, the event (and therefore the request) is completed when the `async void` method yields. The ASP.NET runtime, however, knows that the request is not complete. The problem with `Load` is that the `Page` lifetime just moves to the next step when the `async Load` yields instead of waiting for the `async Load` to complete.

Comment: If you register them, that should work fine. But `async void` does not register itself with `Page`, hence the problems (on .NET 4.0).

Comment: According to http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx the only reliable way to use async in web forms is to register  Page.RegisterAsyncTask. Are you sure that adding async to Page_Load is sufficient ?

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim: It's sufficient. Though I do recommend `RegisterAsyncTask`.

Comment: FWIW, I've seen usage of `Task.Run` (chained with `ContiuneWith` and - of course - without accessing `Result` which would lead to a deadlock) in WebForms in production on .NET 4.5.2 and .NET 4.7, existing there for years and working without problems. One disclaimer is that there were no more than a few dozen co-existing sessions using that `Task.Run` code.

Comment: @OfirD: Sure, `Task.Run` and `ContinueWith` may work, but `Task.Run` is inefficient on ASP.NET, and `ContinueWith` is a dangerous, low-level method.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx the only reliable way to use async in web forms is to call  Page.RegisterAsyncTask.

> The code to support simple things like async Page_Load is extremely
>   complicated and not well-tested for anything beyond basic scenarios.
>
> Using async with voids is not stable or reliable. However, all you
>   have to do is call Page.RegisterAyncTask - it's not any trouble and
>   you'll be in a better more flexible place

.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(LoadSomeData));
}

public async Task LoadSomeData()
{
var clientcontacts = Client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("api/contacts");
var clienttemperature = Client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("api/temperature");

var contacts = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(await clientcontacts);
var temperature = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await clienttemperature);

listcontacts.DataSource = contacts;
listcontacts.DataBind();
Temparature.Text = temperature; 
}
```

Comment: True but it does not wait for async task to complete and goes to next line of code inside Page_Load.